# How to play vimeo videos inline in moblie application and grab seek, play events

Tags: ionic-framework, mobile-application, vimeo-api

We are developing a mobile application (using ionic framework, jquery) and thinking to let our users to share videos from vimeo, youtube etc. in this case we are integrating vimeo video link in iframe. Below are challenges:

1. Not able to play vimeo videos inline in our application:

   - on iPhone device when we play vimeo video from our ionic application it opens in a native video player, on the contrary we want to play it inline in our application itself
   - in case of Youtube video its supported and works well.  They have provide Playsinline property to support it.
   - As per vimeo developers documentation, we have not found any similar video player property to allow inline video rendering
   - Is there any workaround that you suggest to play vimeo video inline inside application?
2. Play, seek & load progress events are not supported in mobile application

   - As per your developers page, play, seek, load progress etc events are not supported in mobile application
   - Is there any workaround to enable these events on our mobile application

Yes, I know there are limitations that vimeo has declared but can someone provide me if there are any workarounds? Your response to our queries is very much important for us.

Reference:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api#event-compatibility

Comment: Also trying to solve the vimeo inline problem, did you guys find any solution?

Comment: player parameters for Youtube will not help you if you'r using Vimeo.

Answer (score 0):

try adding background=1 to your embed code

`<iframe id="player1" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/[video id]?api=1&player_id=player1&background=1" width="630" height="354" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

This wil not work in browsers which revert to the flashplayer.
I don't know if you'll have javascript API functionallity.
This will remove all controls aswell. What I've read, it's still in an experimental fase, but hope it works for you.